# Component renders even before receiving its data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-component

*TLDR:*
Component renders right before my api updates my local data (of which the component uses).

**Detailed Explanation**

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. User clicks "create question" and a modal will appear with all appropriate form inputs.
2. User will enter the actual question in the "question content" field.
3. User will then add several "choices" for that question.
4. User will choose among the created choices the "correct answer" [there is only 1 correct answer per question].
5. User clicks "Add Question" and it will save everything to the database and on the local storage [`questions`, `choices`, and `answers` states]

Here is the flow after the user clicks "Add Question":

- save question [object] via axios post call
- on success, clone the local state (array) `questions` into an array named `tmp_questions`
- create an object through the response from that call, add it on `tmp_questions` and then set `questions` based on `tmp_questions` (I do this because you can't simply append "questions" since it's a state array)

After saving the questions, it will do the same for all the choices and then the answer with the same flow (saving on db, then locally saving it on their respective states).

The `questions` state array looks like this:

```
[
    {_id: 1, content: "which is a food"},
    {_id: 2, content: "which is not a color"},
    ...
]
```

While the `choices` state array is like this:

```
[
    {_id: 1, question_id: 2, content: "blue"},
    {_id: 2, question_id: 2, content: "green"},
    {_id: 3, question_id: 2, content: "apple"},
    ...
]
```

And finally the `answers` state array is like this:

```
[
    {_id: 1, question_id: 2, content (choice_id): 3},
    ...
]
```

I then have a component that iterates on the `questions` state array, display their respective `choices`, then highlights the correct choice based on the `answers` state array:

```
const getAnswer = (question_id) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < props.answers.length; i++) {
        if (props.answers[i].content === question_id) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

<div>
     { props.choices
          ?
          <div>
             {props.choices.map(choice => (
                  <div key={choice._id}>
                       { getAnswer(choice._id) === true
                           ?
                           <div className="alert alert-success mb-1">{choice.content}</div>
                           :
                           <div className="alert alert-secondary mb-1">{choice.content}</div>
                        }
                    </div>
               ))}
            </div>
            :
            <p>No choices</p>
       }
</div>
```

Finally, via `useEffect`, I then call a function called `fetchQuestions` that would make an API call to the database and get all the questions, choices, and answers; then will save them locally. This is done when the page loads.

```
const fetchQuestions =  () => {
    let test_code = params.code
    const url = url_questions + '/' + test_code
    axios.get(url, {
        headers: {
            'auth-token': token
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
            setQuestions(res.data)

            // Fetch Choices
            const choice_url = url_choices + '/' + params.code
            axios.get(choice_url, {
                headers: {
                    'auth-token': token
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                setChoices(res.data)
                setIsGettingData(false)
                setIsGettingQuestions(false)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })

            // Fetch Answers
            const url = url_answers + "/" + params.code

            axios.get(url, {
                headers: {
                    'auth-token': token
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                setAnswers(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err.response)
            })
       }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response.data)
    })
}
```

When the page loads, everything seems to work correctly and the component displays something like this:

[image: component works]

The problem now, is right after I click "Add Question" the component displays something like this:

[image: component doesnt show correct answer]

As you can see, the second question doesn't highlight the correct answer anymore. It does this to all further questions you add. However when you refresh the page, it will now highlight all the correct answers per question. The problem might be on my "Add Question" logic. Here is the complete code:

```
// Add Question
const addQuestion = () => {

    // Check if it is multiple choice and has choices
    if (question_type === 'multiple-choice' && current_choices.length <= 0){
        setHasErrorsAddQuestion(true)
        setErrorAddQuestion("Your question has no choices!")
        return
    }

    // Null Handler
    if (question_content === '' || question_content == null) {
        setHasErrorsAddQuestion(true)
        setErrorAddQuestion("Your question cannot be empty!")
        return
    }

    // No Answer Checker
    if (isEmpty(current_answer) && is_creating_question) {
        if (question_type === 'multiple-choice' || question_type === 'true-false') {
            setHasErrorsAddQuestion(true)
            setErrorAddQuestion("Please select an answer for your question!")
            return
        }
    }

    // Defaults
    setCanAddQuestion(false)
    setHasErrorsAddQuestion(false)
    setErrorAddQuestion("")

    const url = url_questions
    const question = {
        content: question_content,
        type: question_type,
        test: test.code
    }

    axios.post(url, question, {
        headers: {
            'auth-token': token
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
            // Clone Questions and add new Question
            const new_question = res.data
            const temp_questions = [...questions]
            temp_questions.push(new_question)
            setQuestions(temp_questions)

            // Save Choices - Multiple Choice Only
            if (res.data.type === 'multiple-choice') {
                saveChoices(res.data)

                // if (add_choices) {
                //     // // Reset (Success)
                //     // mclose_addquestion()
                //     // setQuestionContent("")
                //     // setQuestionType("multiple-choice")
                //     // setCurrentChoices([])
                //
                //     // fetchQuestions()
                // }
                // else {
                //     // TODO: Delete Question
                //     setCanAddQuestion(true)
                // }
            }

            // Not Multiple Choice
            else {
                mclose_addquestion()
                setQuestionContent("")
                setQuestionType("multiple-choice")
                setCurrentChoices([])
            }
        }
        setCanAddQuestion(true)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        setErrorAddQuestion(err.response.data)
        setHasErrorsAddQuestion(true)
        setCanAddQuestion(true)
    })
}
```

And for the `saveChoices`:

```
// Save Choices - for Multiple Choice Questions
const saveChoices = (question) => {
    const temp_choices = [...choices]
    for (let i = 0; i < current_choices.length; i++) {

        // Check if current choice is the answer
        let is_answer = false
        if (current_answer.temp === current_choices[i].content) {
            is_answer = true
        }

        // Build Choice data
        let seq = i + 1
        const choice = {
            content: current_choices[i].content,
            test: test.code,
            question: question._id,
            sequence: seq
        }

        // Push choices to local temp
        temp_choices.push(choice)

        // Save to DB
        const url = url_choices
        axios.post(url, choice, {
            headers: {
                'auth-token': token
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                // Clone and Add new Choices
                temp_choices[i]._id = res.data._id

                // Update Current Answer Values and save it to DB
                if (is_answer) {
                    let content = ''

                    if (question.type === 'multiple-choice') {
                        content = res.data._id
                    }

                    const answer = {
                        test: params.code,
                        question: res.data.question,
                        type: question.type,
                        content: content
                    }

                    // Save to DB
                    const url = url_answers
                    axios.post(url, answer, {
                        headers: {
                            'auth-token': token
                        }
                    })
                    .then(res => {
                        if (res.status === 200) {
                            // Save Answer Locally
                            const tmp_answers = [...answers]
                            tmp_answers.push(answer)
                            setAnswers(tmp_answers)

                            // Clear Current Answer
                            setCurrentAnswer({})
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err.response.data)
                    })
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.response.data)
        })
    }

    setChoices(temp_choices)

    // Get Answers from DB
    // fetchAnswers()

    // Reset (Success)
    mclose_addquestion(true)
    setQuestionContent("")
    setQuestionType("multiple-choice")
    setCurrentChoices([])
}
```

When I console.log `answers` after saving a question, it displays all the answers of all the questions including the one I just created. However, the component doesn't highlight the correct answer on a freshly created question.

My theory is that right after calling both `addQuestion` and `saveChoices`, the component renders itself even before the `answers` are updated; therefor it couldn't find anything on that array and doesn't highlight the correct choice since it returned `false` on all choices (getAnswer).

Refreshing the page however, it will now work flawlessly since the `useEffect` calls and updates all `questions`, `choices`, and `answers` state arrays even before rendering the component. I cannot just refresh the page every time the user adds a question since that would be borderline annoying. Are there any solutions/work-arounds/alternative ways to fix this?

Comment: You could try and use callbacks like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp) to make sure that your render function is only executed after the question updates (the callback function is shown near the bottom of that page).

Comment: @NO_GUI Thanks so much for your suggestion. I might try using callbacks instead and will update you of the results.